Standard error for optimal solution of a convex optimization problem
Suppose I'm given a sample of IID pairs $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ of non-negative numbers from some distribution $\mathcal{D}$ having a finite mean and covariance matrix. Moreover, I'm given a strictly convex and continuously differentiable function $f$. I would like to find $\theta^*$ which is the optimal solution of the univariate minimization problem
$$
\min_{\theta} \qquad \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ x_i f(\theta)- y_i \theta \right]
$$
Suppose that an optimal solution $\theta^*$ is attained. Is there a well-known closed-form method to estimate the standard error of $\theta^*$? Maybe some other concentration results on $\theta^*$? Possibly with some additional assumptions on $f$?
Some details
Since $f$ is strictly convex and continuously differentiable, the optimal solution is unique and is attained at the solution of the equation
$$
f'(\theta) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}
$$
So, in some sense, $\theta^*$ is related to the ratio in the LHS.
An example
If $f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \theta^2$, then the optimal solution is
$$
\theta^* = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}
$$
In this special case, $\theta^*$ is the ratio.
Moreover, if we assume that $x_i > 0$ for all $i$, then we can write our minimization problem equivalently as
$$
\min_\theta \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \sqrt{x_i} \theta - \frac{y_i}{\sqrt{x_i}} \right]^2
$$
which is just a linear regression with 1 parameter $\theta$. For this we already have theory. However, in general, I do not want to assume that all $x_i$ are positive, and therefore I'm looking for something more general.

What do your brackets mean in the first equation?  Are they intended to indicate absolute value? If not, then why are they even there? Why don't you instead write this much more simply and clearly as $$f(\theta)\sum x_i - \theta \sum y_i,$$ which has the form $b(f(\theta)(a/b) - \theta)$ for $b\gt 0$? Thus, at least when not all $y_i$ are zero, you have a single realization of the non-negative random variable $(a/b)$ from a known distribution (computable from $\mathcal D$).

If the brackets $[\dots]$ relate to the absolute value then possibly relevant is M-estimation. I have never completed a full intuition about the variance of estimators, but I wouldn't be surprised if M-estimators asymptotically approach some variance similar to the maximim likelihood estimate. Also, the function looks similar to a likelihood with a Laplace distribution.

What is the distribution of $y_i$ and $x_i$? In your example $$\theta^* = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$ you may get an infinite variance.
